# Why do we use connect-mongo with express-session, passport, and express?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, passport.js, express-session

I am still new to Passport, and i have created an application with express, passport, and express-session and it's authenticating as expected. but for some reason I keep running into connect-mongo in every tuturial. so please **can you explain what is the role of connect-mongo exactly and/or and it wou be greate if you could provide some good document about it.** thank you for your time sir.

Answer (score 2):

[@ArabDROPS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15462142/arabdrops) first of all, are you using the wrong package for connecting our node app with the mongo database use [Mongoose Package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose)  for connecting our app with the database

In modern web applications, [JWTs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken) are widely used as it scales better than that of a session-cookie

### You can follow this template for when the user login generates token and you can check with middleware not need to use express-session.

## **1. GENERATE JWT TOKEN WHEN USER LOGIN**

Generate Token and Send this token with a response...

```
    router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
      try {
        // checking username
        const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
        !user && res.status(401).json("Wrong Username");
    
        // checking password
        const bytes = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(user.password, process.env.SECRET_KEY);
        const originalPassword = bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
    
        // If password not match return respond
        originalPassword !== req.body.password &&
          res.status(401).json("Wrong Password");
    
        // Creating Json Web Token
    
        const accessToken = jwt.sign(
          { id: user._id, isAdmin: user.isAdmin },
          process.env.SECRET_KEY,
          { expiresIn: "5d" }
        );
    
        // stop sending password to respond
        const { password, ...info } = user._doc;
    
        // Returning User(info) , also sending accessToken
        res.status(200).json({ ...info, accessToken });
      } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json(err);
      }
    });
```

## **2. VERIFY TOKEN MIDDLEWARE**

Create this verify token function used as a MIDDLEWARE in your routes...

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

function verify(req, res, next) {
  const authHeader = req.headers.token;
  if (authHeader) {
    const token = authHeader.split(" ")[1];
    jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET_KEY, (err, user) => {
      if (err) res.status(403).json("Token is not valid");
      req.user = user;
      next();
    });
  } else {
    return res.status(402).json("You are not authorized");
  }
}

module.exports = verify;
```

## **3. VERIFY-IN ROUTES AS AN MIDDLEWARE**

```
const verify = require("../verifyToken");

// CREATE
router.post("/", verify, async (req, res) => {
  if (req.user.isAdmin) {
    const newList = new List(req.body);
    try {
      const savedList = await newList.save();
      res.status(201).json(savedList);
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).json(err);
    }
  } else {
    res.status(403).json("You are not allowed!");
  }
});

// DELETE
router.delete("/:id", verify, async (req, res) => {
  if (req.user.isAdmin) {
    try {
      await List.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id);
      res.status(201).json("The list has been deleted");
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).json(err);
    }
  } else {
    res.status(403).json("You are not allowed!");
  }
});
```

## **CONCLUSION:-**

1. Create a token with jwt.sign when user login...
2. Create a verify function in the root directory export this function...
3. Require this function in routes file use as a middleware...